# What are the limitations of Gravity Sketch?

Tags: design, computer-aided-design

Gravity Sketch is a program (app) for the Oculus VR platform. What are its limitations compared to, say, Fusion 360 (a slightly more traditional design platform?)

It looked like it doesn't provide ways to dimension things (only measure) or to adjust the model's parameters. Can it make fillets, etc.? Is there good interchangeability between it and other programs (export from Gravity Sketch, work on in Fusion, etc.?)

Comment: Does it have documentation or instructions?

Comment: Of course, just wondering if anyone with experience would care to share about any frustrations or obstacles they've found.

Comment: this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum ... please ask one specific, answerable question